# Fantasy book series with 6 "species" or "races" of humanoids

Tags: story-identification

I can't recall the title or the series name, but the books had 6 main species of humanoids. Regular humans, tiny light creatures (almost like fairies that could change their appearance by bending light, or some such), giants, some sort of elves that change color with age and wisdom, and I think one of the others was a sort of doglike humanoid who dressed really flamboyantly and maybe was a really good fighter? I'm also thinking someone catlike, so maybe I'm mixing it up.

I've tried to figure it out a dozen times over the last couple years, but I'm at a loss. I read them in high school maybe 6-7 years ago, and they seemed like older books. There was a scene in a boat and another where they fought in the trees maybe, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: For some reason this really evokes the [Spellsinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellsinger) series.

Comment: It sounds a bit like the world of the Earthdawn roleplaying world, which has been used in a dozen or so novels. Points of similarity: Many races, including humans, Elves, Dwarves, large Trolls, giant Obsidimen, Orcs, Windlings (faeries), and T'Skrang, who dress flamboyantly and often are skilled swordmasters. Points of dissimilarity: I don't think Windlings can change appearance, the Elves don't change color, and the T'Skrang are lizard-like rather than doglike.